# Group By return clarification

Tags: sqlite

I'm working through the Stanford SQL course and came across this question:

*For each movie, return the title and the 'rating spread', that is, the difference between highest and lowest ratings given to that movie. Sort by rating spread from highest to lowest, then by movie title.*

The database structure and data can be found [here](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/DB/SQL/asset/moviedata.html).

The following solution gives the correct result:

```
SELECT Movie.title,  max(Rating.stars)-min(Rating.stars) as spread
FROM Movie, Rating
WHERE Movie.mID = Rating.mID
GROUP BY Rating.mID
ORDER BY spread DESC, Movie.title ASC
```

I'm confused on why it works. I thought "GROUP BY Rating.mID" would cause it to return only one row for each unique Rating.mID (movie), and thus "max(Rating.stars)-min(Rating.stars)" would not work. But it seems I'm wrong and it is finding the correct max and min values within each group of ratings for a movie.

Can someone explain if GROUP BY really returns only a single row per unique Rating.mID, or does it return all rows per group but it is invisible in the result?

Comment: Group by returns a single row per Rating.mID, but it is made up of all the rows that have the same Rating.mID. You can use functions such as min, max, and sum to aggregate/manipulate the values of each column. If you include a column without some kind of aggregation or including it in the group by clause, SQL will throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GROUP BY indeed returns only a single row for each group.

But that is only the result of the SELECT.
The GROUP BY and SELECT clauses are *not* separately executed: while the GROUP BY sorts the original rows into groups, it also runs the aggregation functions over all rows within each group.